# UIViewController is getting retained

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

In my application, I have three `UIViewController` objects.

V1 -> V2 -> V3

When I move from V2 to V3, I'm using push and from V3 to V2 using pop. But somehow, the objects of V3 are being retained.

I thought that when we do pop, all the objects - V3 objects - from the stack are removed. However that's not happening in this case.

Can someone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: not happening probably because you over retain it.

Comment: Can you show us (w/ code) how you do the allocation, init and (auto)release of those viewcontrollers in the pop and push methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
 V3 *v3 = [[[V3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"V3" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
             [self.navigationController pushViewController: v3 animated:YES];
```

this is the standard way of pushing controller in the navigation bar..

Either you are missing the autorelease or release on the v3 or you are retaining it somewhere else..

Comment: I m not autoreleasing it, instead manually releasing it as follows.     V3 *v3 = [[V3 alloc] initWithNibName@"V3"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:v3 animated:YES]; [v3 release]; v3= nil;

Comment: what about retaining it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Just as you push the view controller using the navigation controller add a line below to release it.

Show us some code of what actually your are doing.  Then we can tell you exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Shubhank said, make sure you balance out the retains and releases in these methods within the UIViewController itself:

`viewDidLoad` & `viewDidUnload`

`viewWillAppear:` & `viewWillDisappear:`

Also make sure that you are releasing any property with a "retain" or "copy" attribute in your dealloc method.

As long as you are cleaning up everything properly in dealloc, and your retain/release count for the UIViewController itself is balanced (see Shubhank's answer), you will have no problem and everything will get released as expected.